# Reality Capture output file to forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-realitycapture

is there any way so I can see the results of the Reality Capture API output file in forge Viewer, or do I need to download first then again upload that is the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the Recap API that would work are the following: obj and fbx. In order for you to get a viewable and show it with the Forge Viewer it will need to go through the process of using Model Derivative to translate the file into an SVF.

Here is the steps to take to achieve this:

1st. Use Recap API and set the output as obj or fbx - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/tutorials/create-3d-mesh-from-photos/

2nd. Use Model Derivative API - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/